24.04 LTS Texts don't appear until hover
I installed Ubuntu 24.04. I am facing an issue where texts are not visible until I hover.
Is there anyone facing this issue and is there a way to fix it?
check this video

Thanks for the clarification. I have removed the bug reporting tag.

Are you using NVidia graphics?

Yes. I am using NVIDIA GeForce GT 710

I'm having the exact same issue with a GeForce GTX 780.

@ReubenSiama you should change the accepted answer. Chad's link solved the issue for me.

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu 24.04 screen glitches on gnome apps after install

it is probably because display driver or kernel incompatibility with your vga driver or the UI incompatibility with your vga driver.
you might want to try to use an opensource vga driver.

@Reuben Siama
I have the exact problem except that my current system is running an Nvidia Quadro K600.  Anyway, this worked for me, hope it does for you: Ubuntu 24.04 screen glitches on gnome apps after install

Same issue with Ubuntu 24.04 and NVIDIA GeForce 740M. The add of
GSK_RENDERER=gl
in file /etc/environment with a reboot fix it. Please see Ubuntu 24.04 screen glitches on gnome apps after install
